# How to add a custom script into React app component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to add [this script](https://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/title-blink.php) into my react app.

My `public/index.html` file contains,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script src="../src/scripts/blink.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

My react app loads just fine on my port, bootstrap and font awesome load as expected. However, that particular module does not seem to function properly. I've included all the necessary links as listed [here on Bootstrap's](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) website. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I look at the source code in the client, clicking on `../src/scripts/blink.js` just opens up my landing page in a new tab.

Here's my version of the function for reference,

```
titlebar = val => {
  var msg = "This is side ";
  var speed = 500;
  var pos = val;
  var msg1 = msg + "A";
  var msg2 = msg + "B";
  if (pos == 0) {
    masg = msg1;
    pos = 1;
  } else if (pos == 1) {
    masg = msg2;
    pos = 0;
  }
  document.title = masg;
  timer = window.setTimeout("titlebar(" + pos + ")", speed);
};
titlebar(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this in react, it would probably be beneficial to re-implement this script in a more natural way. For example:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Blinker extends React.PureComponent {

    state = {
        message: 'This is side',
        side: 'A'
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerId = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 500);
    }

    tick = () => {
        let newSide;
        if (this.state.side === 'A') {
            newSide = 'B';
        } else {
            newSide = 'A';
        }
        this.setState({ side: newSide });
    };

    render() {
        return <span>{this.state.message} {this.state.side}</span>;
    }
}
```